# How to subscribe to switchMap

Tags: rxjs

Given a switchMap like this

```
const sw = switchMap(() => {
    if (/*some condition*/) { return this.getDetails().pipe(...) }
    return this.getOtherDetails().pipe(....);
});
```

Ideally I would like to use this, for example as follows

```
from(sw).subscribe(....)
```

but that doesn't work :)

So how can I do this. I can think of one solution

```
of(true).pipe(sw).subscribe(...)
```

But this doesn't feel right, or does it? I can image RxJS has a much better solution for this kind of problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: You don't need to use `switchMap` at all. Have a look at `iif` https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/iif function

Comment: Thanks martin, `iif` is much better!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@martin's comment is right.

The reason it doesn't feel right is because you're not starting with an event or anything you're waiting for. You might as well have a method like

```
getAppropriateDetails$() {
  if (/*some condition*/) {
    return this.getDetails$();
  }
  this.getOtherDetails$();
});
```

and then you can use it like

```
this.getAppropriateDetails$().pipe(
  ...
).subscribe (
  ...
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use *tenary* operator.

```
([some condition] ? this.getDetails().pipe(...) : this.getOtherDetails().pipe(...)).subscribe(...);
```